# Find a file in the solution

Tags: c#, mstest

I have an xml file say samplexml.xml and I have stored it in a folder called SampleFolder. Here how the Hierarchy is:

Solution->Project->SampleFolder->samplexml.xml. Suppose I am in a class called TestClass.cs that is in the project, How can I read all the contents of the xml file in a string.

Let's say,

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void TestMethod()
   {
       //TODO: Read all the contents of the xml file in a string.
   }

}
```

How do I do this??

Comment: Use XMLReader...Since you have not even attempted to use it, that can be an exercise for you, come back with actual questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
string exePath = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string xmlPath = Path.Combine(exePath, "SampleFolder");
string fileName = Path.Combine(xmlPath, "SampleXML.xml");
```

Remember you should set compiler to copy xml file to destination dir